# Can an Indian passport holder without a travel history apply for a UK visa?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I am from India and my travel history includes a tourist visit in 2014 to Dubai UAE and one week in January 2016 to China on a business visa. Now, my wife and I want to vist the UK for two weeks. My wife has a newly-issued passport and has not traveled. Should we first create a travel history for her, or should we go ahead and apply for the UK tourist/visitor visa?

Answer (score 6):

You need to apply for a Standard Visitor Visa for yourself and your wife. In order for the visa to be granted, the immigration office has to be convinced that you will leave at the end of your stay.

From the UK visas and immigrations [website](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility/):

> You must always show that:
>
> • you’ll leave the UK at the end of your visit
>
> • you’re able to support yourself and any dependents for the duration of your trip
>
> • you’re able to pay for your return or onward journey and any other costs relating to your visit
>
> • you have proof of any business or other activities you want to do in the UK, as allowed by the Visitor Rules

Your wife's lack of travel history shouldn't be a major problem if you can satisfy these requirements. Information about documents needed for supporting an application can also be found in the GOV UK website.

The visitor rules are laid out in [Appendix V of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).